# Checkbutton always returns True

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, boolean

Comrades,
I faced a problem while working with `tkinter` library.
Here is a code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class Doc_Search:      
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.var6 = IntVar()
        self.var7 = IntVar()
#Winglets checkbuttons
        self.C2 = Checkbutton(self.labelframeA, variable = self.var6, offvalue = 0, onvalue = 1, command = self.onWinglets)
        self.C2.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky = 'W')

        self.R9 = Radiobutton(self.labelframeA, text = "Blended", state=DISABLED, variable = self.var7, value = 1, command = self.Wing_key)
        self.R9.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='W')

        self.R10 = Radiobutton(self.labelframeA, text = "SSW", state=DISABLED, variable = self.var7, value = 2, command = self.Wing_key)
        self.R10.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='W'+'N')

    def onWinglets(self):
               self.key5 = self.var6.get()
               if self.key5:
                  self.R9['state']='normal'
                  self.R10['state']='normal'
                  return True
               else:
                  self.var7.set(0)
                  self.R9['state']='disabled'
                  self.R10['state']='disabled'
                  return False
        myapp = Doc_Search(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Next function, that depends on `onWinglets(self)`

```
    def Wing_key(self): 
        if self.onWinglets:
```

Works as if `onWinglets(self)` always returns `True` (despite `Checkbutton` is pressed or not). It is kind of weird. Who can help to solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

PS: I tried to check the performance of `onWinglets(self)` function as:

```
z = myapp.onWinglets()
print(z)
```

With following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "windows_tk_1.py", line 313, in <module>
    z = myapp.onWinglets()
  File "windows_tk_1.py", line 220, in onWinglets
    self.R9['state']='normal'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1340, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1333, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1324, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".139943983318912.139943983320312"
```

Thanks to everybody for help!

Answer (score -1):

Try to rewrite your condition to :

```
if self.var6.get() == 1 :
```

Maybe you misunderstand that `self.key5 = self.var6.get()` does not convert `IntVar()` value to boolean indicator. Just test `var6.get()` directly.

Feel free to change tested value to `0`.

Comment: I did the following (in second function): 
`def Wing_key(self): 
        if self.var6.get() == 1:`
Looks like it works. Thanks!